# Создание XML файла для POST запроса C#

Tags: c#, xml, post

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть пример XML файла. Каким самым простым способом можно создать XML для POST запроса на основе этого примера?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251" ?>
<product>
<prequest>
<req>
<AddressReq>
<street>Горького</street>
<houseNumber>1</houseNumber>
<apartment>38</apartment>
<city>Магадан</city>
<postal>685000</postal>
<addressType>1</addressType>
</AddressReq>
<AddressReq>
<street>Цветочная</street>
<houseNumber>5</houseNumber>
<block>11</block>
 <apartment>143</apartment>
<city>Магадан</city>
<postal>685000</postal>
<addressType>2</addressType>
</AddressReq>
<IdReq>
<idNum>273412</idNum>
<idType>21</idType>
<seriesNumber>6439</seriesNumber>
<issueCountry>г. Магадан</issueCountry>
<issueDate>2006-03-18</issueDate>
<issueAuthority>ОВД Центральное, к/п 255</issueAuthority>
</IdReq>
<InquiryReq>
<ConsentReq> 
<consentFlag>Y</consentFlag> 
<consentDate>2016-01-20</consentDate> 
<consentExpireDate>2021-10-21</consentExpireDate> 
<consentPurpose>4</consentPurpose> 
<otherConsentPurpose>Job pre-screening</otherConsentPurpose> 
<reportUser>DG Human Resources Incorporated</reportUser> 
<liability>Y</liability> 
</ConsentReq>
<inqPurpose>01</inqPurpose>
<inqAmount>10000</inqAmount>
<currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
</InquiryReq>
<PersonReq>
<name1>Фамилия</name1>
<first>Георгий</first>
<paternal>Отчество</paternal>
<gender>1</gender>
<birthDt>1946-07-06</birthDt>
<placeOfBirth>Москва</placeOfBirth>
</PersonReq>
<RequestorReq>
<MemberCode>0000BB000000</MemberCode>
<UserID>0000BB000001</UserID>
<Password>password</Password>
</RequestorReq>
<RefReq>
<product>CHST</product>
</RefReq>
<IOType>B2B</IOType>
<OutputFormat>XML</OutputFormat>
<lang>ru</lang>
</req>
</prequest>
</product>
```

Comment: У пост запроса есть GetRequestStream метод верно (посмотрите пример отправки POST запроса)? Передавайте туда xml.

Comment: Наверное не правильно выразился. У меня есть файл xml, мне его передали. И мне надо создать такого же формата файл xml.  А вот тут затык.

Comment: Тогда 1) создаёте массив `byte[]` делаете requestStream.read в массив, а потом fileStream.Write.  2) в версии NET 4.0 появилась ф-ция CopyTo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx открываете файл на запись, и делаете RequestStream.CopyTo.  P.S. RequestStream нужно позицию выставить в RequestStream.Position=0 перед копированием. **Нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934295/c-sharp-save-a-file-from-a-http-request решение**

Comment: Проще всего создавать xml с помощью [XElement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/creating-xml-trees-linq-to-xml-2).